# Which load resistor value for amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image: spec sheet audio chip]

I have build this circuit succesfully but I need more volume. This is an audio chip with animal sounds.

I tried to remove the transistor and connect the out pin to a class d amplifier breakout. I get only a very low volume then.

My idea is to amplify the sound first with the S8050 transistor, and then connect to the amplifier. When I remove the speaker from the circuit from the spec sheet I need to replace that with a load resistor. I have however no idea which value to pick. The output will then be between the load resistor and the transistor (right?)

I use a 8 ohm speaker.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without reading the datasheet carefully, but I think you are correct about the basic idea. I suggest using an 8 Ohm resistor to start with. If you use a differential input class D amplifier, you could possibly take your output from directly across the resistor.

Comment: I decided to go for the solution below because i could omit the transistor and the volume is high enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of googling would have found this circuit

[image]

Nothing special about the audio amp used (HT82V793) so just about any audio amp should do.

Comment: Thank you i didn't found this circuit. I have a lot of hq noise now.